# Safari ignore height auto in img in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I have a website developed with HTML, CSS (Bootstrap), JS and PHP.
The problem came with the images in Safari. My img tag has a class **img-fluid** which has this to it's CSS:

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

All works fine in all devices, except in Safari.

This is how it looks in Safari:

[image]

And this is how it is supposed to look like:

[image]

This happens to all the images in the web.

I have this meta tag:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

I think the problem is that Safari ignores the `height: auto;` and all the images shrink to 100% of the container height, or something like that.

Comment: did you try using a fixed ```width: 100%``` and ```max-width: /*as container*/``` ?

Comment: Have you cleared the cache before refreshing?

Comment: @ProblemChild yes I did and nothing, same result. And I have cache disabled.

Comment: which ```display``` have your ```meta``` superior label?

Comment: @ProblemChild If you asking about the `display` of parent node, I have `display: flex` and the tree of the HTML is div (container with `display: flex`) -> div (container-image with `display: flex`) -> div (container-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the `display` of the parent container. I change de `display: flex` to `display: block` in the parent div (`div` which contains the `img` tag) and the images start to working fine.

Thanks Problem Child for give me the right way :)